# Mismatch in pronouns grammatical?

Tags: pronouns

> **Adults** should learn their role in society even if **you** don't like to
> live in it.

There's a mismatch in pronoun here, is this ok? I thought it was ok, because the pronoun you is general and can be used to refer to anyone and nost a particular person you're directly talking to. Is this correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that there is a mismatch. I would suggest either

> Adults should learn their role in society even if they don't like to live in it.

or

> As an adult, you should learn your role in society even if you don't like to live in it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Adults** should learn their role in society even if **you** don't like to live in it.

In this case, the pronoun *you* is generally interpreted as *a non-referential you*. The non-referential *you* is just a less formal variant of *one* and used to talk about people in general (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002: 1467). So in this case, *you* refers to people in general, including the **adults**.